# How to prevent long-running backup job from being killed

Tags: linux, memory-management, backup, tar

How do you prevent a long-running memory-intensive tar-based backup script from getting killed?

I have a cron job that runs daily a command like:

```
tar --create --verbose --preserve-permissions --gzip --file "{backup_fn}" {excludes} / 2> /var/log/backup.log
```

It writes to an external USB drive. Normally the file generated is 100GB, but after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16, now the log file shows the process gets killed about 25% of the way through, presumably because it's consuming a lot of memory and/or putting the system under too much load.

How do I tell the kernel not to kill this process, or tweak it so it doesn't consume so many resources that it needs to be killed?

Comment: you'll need to edit your Q to show the relevant portion of the logs. If all you see is "tar process killed" without any reason or other data, then we have no way of helping, except to throw ideas at the wall and see what sticks. You might do better posting the http://askubuntu.com as changing versions seems to be the culprit. Good luck.

Comment: A more simpler approach...use an external tool like `logrotate` to do the log rotation-*compression job for you and the copy the respective compressed file.... https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/

Comment: @shellter, The log literally just says "Killed", which I've only seen happen to processes consuming too much memory. I've seen it in others distros/releases, but this is the first time my backup script has been killed in this fashion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain about the fact that - the gets killed due to consuming too much memory, then you can try increasing the `swappiness` value in `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness`. By increasing `swappiness` you might able to get away from this scenario. You can also try tuning `oom_kill_allocating_task`, default is `0` , which tries to find out the rouge memory-hogging task and kills that one. If you change that one to `1`, `oom_killer` will kill the calling task.

If none of the above works then you can try `oom_score_adj` under `/proc/$pid/oom_score_adj`. `oom_score_adj` accepts value range from `-1000` to `1000`. Lower the value less likely to be killed by `oom_killer`. If you set this value to `-1000` then it disables oom killing. But, you should know what exactly you are doing.

Hope this will give you some idea.